# How to write a table from R into Excel

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to write a table from R into Excel. Here is some sample code:

```
library(XLConnect)
wb     <- loadWorkbook("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\Example.xls", create=TRUE)
output <- as.table(output)
createSheet(wb, name="Worksheet 1")
writeWorksheet(wb, output, sheet="Worksheet 1")
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

But it seems that the `writeWorksheet` function converts the table into a dataframe. This makes the data look messy and unformatted. I want the table structure to be preserved. How would I modify the above code?

Comment: What class is the original `output` object? Have you tried inserting it directly into `writeWorksheet` without transforming it to a table first? And by "write a table (...) into Excel" do you mean you want the file to be of XLS extension or does something more universal such as CSV do?

Comment: This has been asked myriad times (e.g. [How to save a data frame in a txt or excel file separated by columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514694/how-to-save-a-data-frame-in-a-txt-or-excel-file-separated-by-columns))

Comment: @John I disagree. The issue here is that `writeWorksheet` converts the table to a data frame, which essentially melts the table from wide to long format.

Comment: OK joran, I accept that it's an intersection of two commonly asked questions that could have been answered with a little more searching. I guess I can see it both ways. I'll keep my close vote. I believe an attempt to do some searches and solve this problem would have resulted in a different question than we have here...if it resulted in one at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `writeWorksheet` converts the table object to a data frame. The way that happens is that R will basically "melt" it into long format, whereas a table object is typically printed to the console in "wide" format.

It is a bit of a nuisance, but you generally have to manually convert the table into a data frame that matches the format you're after. An example:

```
library(reshape2)
tbl <- with(mtcars,table(cyl,gear))
> tbl
   gear
cyl  3  4  5
  4  1  8  2
  6  2  4  1
  8 12  0  2
> as.data.frame(tbl)
  cyl gear Freq
1   4    3    1
2   6    3    2
3   8    3   12
4   4    4    8
5   6    4    4
6   8    4    0
7   4    5    2
8   6    5    1
9   8    5    2
> tbl_df <- as.data.frame(tbl)
> final <- dcast(tbl_df,cyl~gear,value.var = "Freq")
> final
  cyl  3 4 5
1   4  1 8 2
2   6  2 4 1
3   8 12 0 2
> class(final)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Then you should be able to write *that* data frame to the Excel worksheet with no problem.